# Code works perfectly when executed line by line (using f8) but gives error when ran fully, shows error '424' object required

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer

I'm trying to scrape data from this site [link](http://www.mca.gov.in/mcafoportal/viewPublicDocumentsFilter.do)

Using the code below

```
Sub Scrape()


Dim objIE As InternetExplorer
Dim ele As Object
Dim y As Integer
Dim result As String


Set objIE = New InternetExplorer
objIE.Visible = True
objIE.navigate "http://www.mca.gov.in/mcafoportal/viewPublicDocumentsFilter.do"

Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

objIE.document.getElementById("companyName").Value = "tata"

objIE.document.getElementById("companyChk").Click

objIE.document.getElementById("viewDocuments_0").Click

Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

y = 1

For Each ele In objIE.document.getElementById("results").getElementsByTagName("tr") 'error displayed here
    Debug.Print ele.textContent
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & y).Value = ele.Children(0).textContent
    'put text of 2nd 'td' in col B
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & y).Value = ele.Children(1).textContent
    'put text of 3rd 'td' in col C
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & y).Value = ele.Children(2).textContent
    'put text of 4th 'td' in col D
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & y).Value = ele.Children(3).textContent
    'increment row counter by 1
    y = y + 1
    'repeat until last ele has been evaluated
    Next

 End Sub
```

When I run this line by line it works but while run it fully it shows

> error '424' : object required.

I have no clue why that is happening

[image: This is what watch window looks like]

Comment: Is `objIE.document.getElementById("results")` nothing on this line?

Comment: Yes error is on this line `objIE.document.getElementById("results").getElementsByTagName("tr")`

Comment: What I meant to clarify which of the objects `objIE` or `objIE.document` or `objIE.document.getElementById("results")` or `objIE.document.getElementById("results").getElementsByTagName("tr")` is required. Try debugging the code with `Watch Window` on, add these watches and check which of the objects is missing.

Comment: I have added the watch window image, it says object required for `objIE.document.getElementById("results").getElementsByTagNam‌​e("tr")` but i don't understand how do I rectify this